# Displaying has_and_belongs_to_many array in emberjs and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I've got below JSON returning from an API endpoint

```
{
    users: [
    {
    id: 3,
    email: "example@gmail.com",
    title: "Mr",
    first_name: "Hi",
    last_name: "Hey",
    position: "Web Dev",
    work_phone: "123456",
    company: "Comp",
    sign_in_count: 0,
    last_sign_in_ip: null,
    confirmed_at: null,
    created_at: "2013-11-08T03:30:21.160Z",
    roles: [
    {
    id: 2,
    name: "booth_rep",
    resource_id: null,
    resource_type: null,
    created_at: "2013-11-11T06:14:16.062Z",
    updated_at: "2013-11-11T06:14:16.062Z"
    }
    ]
    }]
}
```

Is there a way to use this with Emberjs and Emberdata to display role `name` in my `users` handlebars template?

Does it have to be specified in the model?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like they added many to many in this commit:
https://github.com/emberjs/data/commit/7f752ad15eb9b9454e3da3f4e0b8c487cdc70ff0

So so all you need to do is define the model

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  ...
  roles: DS.hasMany();
});

App.Role = DS.Model.extend({
  ...
  users: DS.hasMany();
});
```

Then in your user template

```
{{#each role in roles}}
  {{role.name}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understand your question correctly, but you can return a result from $.getJSON from your routes model method, if you want:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return $.getJSON( ... );
    }
});
```

I created a simple example, which displays a couple of info from your data with handlebars:
http://jsfiddle.net/x3CEU/